# How to embed a MP4 video in ASP MVC cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mp4

I enhance a mobile page by ASP MVC. How can I embed the video file in the cshtml page that iphone/android can autoplay the video when browse the page?

Need to use html5 ?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: A HTML5 video tag is the only way to go in this case.

Comment: what happens if you can't use html5?  not really a solution

Comment: now [nuget package available for HTML5 Audio & Video, Please check this link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MVC4.Video/), [DEMO](http://mvc4video.apphb.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between ASP.NET MVC or any other web development framework.

Here is sample from [w3schools.com on HTML5 video autoplay Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_video_autoplay.asp)

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```